# Presenter-only pop-up in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, presentation

Is it possible to show a pop-up message (using VBA in Powerpoint) to the presenter which won't be visible to the "audience"?

Edit: Of course, it would be nice if you could tell me "how".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean when working with two screens? I think it is possible...

Comment: while in presenter view (the view that comes with office 2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

Add a userform with a label to contain the text you want to display.

Add this to the vba project:

```
Sub PopUp()
    With UserForm1
        .Show (vbModeless)
        .Left = 100
    End With
End Sub
```

Add a shape to any slide where you want to display the popup and give it an action setting of Run Macro:  PopUp

This assumes that you've accepted the default userform name; change the subroutine to reflect any name changes if you like.

It also assumes that the main monitor is on the left side; if not, you'll need to change the .Left value.